# A one-dimensional periodic structure is the simplest type of photonics crystal and any such one-dimensional system has a band-gap?

Tags: optics, material-science, crystals, electronic-band-theory, photonics

My textbook says the following:

> A one-dimensional periodic structure, such as a multilayer film (a Bragg mirror), is the simplest type of photonics crystal, and Lord Rayleigh showed that any such one-dimensional system has a band-gap.

I have the following questions:

1. What is meant here by a "one-dimensional system"?
2. Why must any such one-dimensional system have a band-gap (what is the physics that necessitates this)?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

EDIT:

Found more information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_crystal#One-dimensional_photonic_crystals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An example of such a system given by Lord Rayleigh [1] is a string loaded with masses at regular intervals. The "one dimension" in this case is the dimension along the length of the string. An analogous structure is a series of films with different material properties, again varying at regular intervals in one dimension. For example, see the image below (from [here](https://www.rp-photonics.com/bragg_mirrors.html)), which illustrates a repeating pattern of films with different indices of refraction. The one dimension is the $x$-axis here.

[image]

Lord Rayleigh's result was basically that certain ranges of wavelengths of incident light (or wavelengths of mechanical waves in the loaded string example) are totally reflected by such a structure. In the above image you can see that the grey curve shows a wave of a certain wavelength passing through the periodic structure, whereas the blue curve shows a different wavelength decaying as it enters.

One way you could think about this result is that there is an interplay between the periodicity of the one-dimensional structure and that of the incident wave. For certain wavelengths this interplay leads to the a wave that dissipates away within the structure.

[1] On the Maintenance of Vibrations by Forces of Double Frequency, and on the Propagation of Waves Through a Medium Endowed with a Periodic Structure. Lord Rayleigh, Phil. Mag., S.5, vol.24, no.147, August 1887, pp.145-59